# Where are the repair kits in Madhouse difficulty?

Tags: resident-evil-7

I found them both on Normal but when replaying on Madhouse, when I got to where I found the first one, all I found in its place was an Antique Coin.

Where can I find the repair kits on Madhouse difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

When you leave the main house, go down the steps and turn hard right and behind the bushes, opposite the side with the tearaway chunk of wall, the repair kit is on the ground, next to some solid fuel.

Comment: Is this the only repair kit on madhouse?

Comment: Second repair kit is exactly where it is on normal difficulty, and its location is hinted with treasure photo.

Answer (score 0):

One is when you first leave the main house, go down the steps, search in the back of the bushes just to the right of the stairs

Comment: That sounds like the one or easy/normal, that the OP has described in the question. Is it not?

Comment: @musefan, answer is completely correct. On Madhouse, first repair kit is directly below window, where separation agent once was on easy/normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Repair Kits total (as well as repairable items).

The first is located in Yard just outside Main House to the right from entrance in bushes:

[image: Location 1]

The second is in Test Area behind mannequin head (to get this one it's required to have treasure photo from Main House - Master Bedroom Storage):

[image: Location 2]